# How many permutations of [9] are there in which exactly 5 numbers are in their original position?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

> How many permutations of [9] are there in which exactly 5 numbers are in their
>   original position?

My professor does not mean equivalence class, she means the set of positive integers less than or equal to 9: so {${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$}.

This looks like a derangement problem. So my first intuition is to count the number of possible permutations of all 9 numbers, which is simply $9!$, then subtract the number of derangements which would be $D_5$. So my answer would be $9!-D_5$.

Am I thinking of this the correct way? What's a better way of going about solving problems like this Any tips?

Comment: $D_5$ is rather small, so you are claiming that almost every permutation qualifies.  That is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  First choose the five numbers which will be in their original positions.  How many ways to do that?  Then you need a derangement of the remaining four.  How many of those are there?

Comment: So, let's suppose all the odd numbers stay in their original position. There's only one way to do that. That means, we need to derange the remaining 4. So there are 9 derangements total for those 4 numbers ($D_4$)?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Cool that makes sense. When do we use complementary counting, to subtract $D_4$ from $9!$? Because the answer to this problem is just $D_4$?

Comment: No, you need to multiply by the number of ways to choose the fixed ones. You use complementary counting when it is the easiest way to the answer

Comment: the answer was actually 9 choose 5 * 9

Comment: That is exactly what I said. The last $9$ is the number of derangements of $4$